# Using someone else's technique in your own patterns

Tags: knitting, pattern-drafting

Say I pick up a pattern from some designer which has a neat technique they use (for example, [fission knitting by Mary W. Martin](https://www.ravelry.com/bundles/fission-knitting)) that I believe they invented, and certainly make a business out of teaching, and then I wanted to start designing, and maybe selling, my own patterns with it. What is the proper etiquette/requirements for that?

For example, nobody who writes pi shawl patterns ever seems to credit Zimmerman in them, and basically everything falls under the umbrella of "technique", but conversely it also just feels like it would be kinda scummy to just lift the technique like that, even if it would be a genuinely different pattern.

Comment: Hi Brandon, welcome to Arts & Crafts! Just as a heads-up: I'm not entirely sure your question can fully be answered here on this website, as it might have legal aspects. Have you tried contacting the person you think you're copying from?

Comment: No,  because it is mostly idle wondering at this point, and more for the future.

Comment: She may have mastered and is certainly capitalizing on it but I doubt she invented the technique. This is an age old thing in the arts... how much can you borrow before you are stealing. Reference Picasso's quote on good vs great artists. Not a lawyer but unless you are directly copying her patterns to teach you should be good. Betting you could find examples of this technique that predate all of us.